# Convergence of set distance in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's define the distance between a point $z$ and a set $A\subseteq X$ of a metric  space $(X,d)$ as follows:
$$\text{dist}(z,A)=\inf\{d(z,a):a \in A\}.$$

Suppose for every non empty $A\subseteq X$ we have that 
$$\text{dist}(x_n,A)\to \text{dist}(x_0,A) .$$ 
I want to prove that $x_n \to x_0$ in $(X, d)$.

I have already proven the other way around. But I can't even get started with this way. Please some help, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try to set $A = \{x_0\}$.

Comment: I tried setting $A=${$x_0$} and I completed the proof . However I still need to prove this for every possible $A\subseteq$$X$ . How do I go next ?

Comment: ? Didn't you say that you have proven the other way around? @StefM

Comment: I am sorry maybe i did not express myself clearly . I have already proven that if we have $x_n \to x_0$ in $(X, d)$ than $$\text{dist}(x_n,A)\to \text{dist}(x_0,A) .$$ I am currently working on the opposite direction . Your idea to set $A_0$={$x_0$} , proved my claim but only for one instance . I need to prove it for every possible, non-empty A$\subseteq$X

Comment: You need to prove $x_n \to x_0$. In this direction you do not need all the $A$'s: Only using $A = \{x_0\}$ would gives $x_n \to x_0$. @StefM (That is, try to use $\text{dist}(x_n, \{x_0\}) \to \text{dist} (x_0, \{x_0\})$ to show that $x_n \to x_0$)

Answer (score 0):

Since for every non empty $A\subseteq X$ we have that dist($x_n$,$A$)->dist($x_0$,$A$) , i choose $A=${$x_0$} . I can do that because $x_0$$\epsilon$X is well defined . Doing so we get dist($x_n$,$x_0$)->dist($x_0$,$x_0$) <=> inf{d($x_n$,$x_0$)} ->inf{d($x_0$,$x_0$)} <=> inf{d($x_n$,$x_0$)} ->inf{$0$)=$0$ <=> For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $n_0$ such as for every $n>n_0$ , inf{d($x_n$,$x_0$)}$<\varepsilon$<=>inf{d($x_n$,$x_0$)}$=0$ ,for every $n>n_0$. So we have that d($x_n$,$x_0$)=$0$ for every $n>n_0$ => d($x_n$,$x_0$)->$0$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: $\operatorname{dist}(x_n, \{x_0\}) = \inf \{d(x_n, x_0\} = d(x_n, x_0)$ because we take the inf of just one real number. And $d(x_n, x_0) = 0$ only happens when $x_n = x_0$, by the definition of a metric, so that cannot be right.

Comment: Note that $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ iff $d(x_n, x_0) \rightarrow 0$ in any metric space.